# Why do ukulele players not use the G-string?

Tags: technique, ukulele

Well, obviously, they do, but in solo/fingerpicking, the only time I've ever seen a note written on the G-string in tab is as part of a chord. **Why do melodic  structures neglect to use the G-string?** Is there an ergonomic reason, or something else? Or are there a bunch of counterexamples I'm overlooking?

*(High G. On a Low G ukulele, it's obviously used way more.)*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The G-string can certainly be used in fingerstyle.  The two books that I used to learn fingerstyle, Rob MacKillop's [20 Easy Fingerstyle Studies for Ukulele](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0786687223) and John King's [Famous Solos and Duets for the 'Ukulele](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0786687568) both use the G-string extensively.

That having been said, because the High-G is tuned between the E- and A- strings, all of the notes here are duplicated on those strings.  Therefore, when you are learning scales, you don't really need it.  For example, when you are learning the C Major scale on the Ukulele, you will start on the open C-string and play the C and D there, then move to the E-string and play the E, F, and G there, and finally move to the A-string and finish with the A, B, and C.

What the G-string does do for you is make it easier to play some intervals.  For example, take a look at these measures from "Banjo Schottische" in John King's book:

[image: excerpt from Banjo Schottische arr. John King]

There are a lot of G notes in there, and playing those notes on the open G-string allows you to play successive notes on two different strings, which is much easier than playing two back-to-back notes on the same string.